# robust camera calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I will try and be specific about my question, firstly i am doing a project for 3d image reconstruction using a camera. I have completed camera calibration but it is not robust occlussions, such as placing object on chessboard it won't detect the corners. Is there a way of mopdifying the program, or can i use the corners detected before placing object and how can  i use those corners to detect the corners without occlussion.

i was thinking of using the corners representing the 4 corners of the chessboard, display it and then i can place object on chessboard.

help would be appreciated in how i can modify or use the current camera calibration program to deal with occlusions i.e. placing object on chessboard.

Answer (score 1):

For robust object detection, write a program that can detect a larger number of features, and then test whether a sufficiently high percentage of the features is present.

For a chessboard, you could try to find the 112 edges between squares, and see if they line up. It won't matter if you miss a few of those 112.

Comment: its not that it misses the corners it just doesn't detect any corners when there is occlusion like an object. i just want the four outer corners detected. then it would use these corners to measure the points or features of an image

Comment: @SeifSharif: Obviously. But if you know where the 4 edges are (and they're unlikely to be entirely occluded), then it's easy to calculate where the corner must be. Think `|_`

Comment: Thinking all the time, i realized that atleast one will always be occluded. behind the object.

Comment: also the problem is when it doesn't detect 100% of the features it just doesn't find any features.

Comment: @SeifSharif: That's an implementation bug, not a fundamental problem with the algorithm. (Obviously, if detected not 100% of the known features but only 90%, then you DID detect some features)

Comment: but thats the problem, it wont detect anything unless all the features are present and not occluded and i am using findchessboardcorner. i will be if it detect 80% but with the functions its either 100% or 0%

Comment: That's the bug there. You use features to find the position of the board; with 80% features you still find the board. With the board position known, you calculate where its corners must be.

Comment: any hints on how i may go about doing this?